# How can I make a readmore button show images and h3 tags after the first paragraph in the article

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, click, show-hide

**Hello-I have been able to make the ".readmore" button work to show the paragraph tag show.  Unfortunately the h3 tag and image are not being displayed when i click on the button. Please help so each post/article dont look to long on my page. Please see the full code here--
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyVgZo**

**HTML:**

```
<section id="main">
        <div class="container">
            <section id="posts">
                <article class="post">

                     <section class="primavera">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                <!-- image top -->


                        </div>
                    </section>

                    <h1 >Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                    <h2 class="bold">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, </p>
                    <span class="readmore" style="display: block;"><a href="#">Read more &gt;</a></span>
                     <p class="hide" id="show-this-on-click" >remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

                     <h3 class="hide" id="show-this-on-click" >NEED TO HAVE IT SHOW</h3>



                     <section class="amarillo hide" id="show-this-on-click" >
                        <div class="wrapper">
                    <!-- image top -->


                        </div>
                    </section>


                    <span class="readless hide" style="display: none;"><a href="#">Read less &gt;</a></span>

                </article>
            </section>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: `show-this-on-click` should probably be a class. IDs are intended to uniquely identify each element, so there should only be one element per ID on the page. I don't have your image, but here's the pen with working readmore and readless buttons: http://codepen.io/shigidaMark/pen/JXLjGw

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok,there's a few things which need to be fixed.

1) There should only ever be one node with a given id attribute. You have multiple nodes with `id="show-this-on-click"`. You'll want to remove the extra id attributes so that only one node has `id="show-this-on-click"`. Or if you follow my example you can just remove all of the id attributes.

2) There is no image tag. I'd add this `<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="more_content"></img>` Where you want your image. I see you're using the background of the section with class amarillio. That would also work if it was shown and hidden along with the rest of addtional content.

3) Your javascript looks like it was pasted in twice. You'll need to remove the second copy.

4) Your spans can be replaced with divs. Once you do that you can remove the style="display: block;" attribute. Almost never is it a good idea to make a span a block. Instead just use a div element.

Once those are done we can begin fixing the code. It looks like you are confusing the roles of ids and classes. I'd remove the id attribute from every node with `id='show-this-on-click'`, and on those nodes which had that id I'd add a show-this-on-click class. That means you'll need to change your javascript, so that the lines with `$('#show-this-on-click')` become `$('.show-this-on-click')`

Inside your click handler for the readless class you have another readmore class handler. That can be deleted.

In your code you have two section elements with class amarillo. It looks like this is how you intend to add the image. I'd remove those and add an img tag. That way your code which matches the img tag will have an img to act on. In my example I removed the code which acted on all img elements and instead act on all elements with a particular class.

You can see my modifications to your code [here](http://codepen.io/DanielOliverThomson/pen/jqzOWm/).

Comment: Hi Dan, Just saw your response. Thank soooo much for taking the time to look at my code and adjust. I will make the suggested changes to make each post look better. Again THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: You're welcome. If you found it useful please mark my answer as your [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Hi Dan-Everything works perfectly but when I try to add another article/post in the same page and click on "read more" both articles open at the same time. Is there a way to make each read more button open individually?

Comment: Adding more articles will make this a much more complex problem. Will you be adding articles from some server side web frame work like Ruby or Django? I updated the [code pen](http://codepen.io/DanielOliverThomson/pen/jqzOWm), but you should probably play with the original a while until you understand how it works.

Comment: This is just what i needed. I am new to java script so there is a lot I need to start learning and your code is perfect. I am adding article/posts which are all in one page and to answer your question, no,  im not using ruby or django. Not sure if i will eventually change it but for now the code works perfectly ! thanks again